# How to patch concrete board plaster job

Tags: plaster, patch

I removed the trim around my back door and was left with the monstrosity pictured.

The new trim I want to install is about 1/2" skinnier so I was wondering if there is a easy(ish)
way to patch this?

If it's too much of a hassle I can just find wider trim that will cover but I was hoping to match it to the same stuff in the rest of my house. [image]

Comment: That looks like ordinary drywall (on top of old plaster), not concrete-board (tile backer.) Unless it's all plaster, no board?

Comment: Ah, the top part of the picture made me think it was backer but didn't realize that was drywall just assumed it was plaster. So I guess my best bet would just be to cut out the crumbling section and put a piece of drywall up

Comment: As long as the new piece is the same thickness as the existing wall board it's fine to use gypsum board. You'll need to tape the seem and cover with compound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

A) Install the new trim and fill the remaining gap with Spackle and/or drywall. Or:

B) Install a section of drywall to fill this gap and han install your trim on top of it. (This is probably the best route to take.